# Error: You appear to have guava-jdk5 on your project buildScript or buildSrc classpath

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I'm getting this error since I deleted the project from my local folder and cloned my project from git to a new folder. The solutions I've found online so far seems to have different dependencies than mine.

Here is the `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: what is `classpath 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'` good for ?!

Comment: I am not exactly sure when and why I added that line but commenting it out doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: alright, replacing that line with "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0" seems to have fixed the issue